# Equivalent of SQL Server HASHBYTES('sha1', @userpwd ) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, hash, encoding

I am trying  to migrate some stored procedures to C# code.

I am trying to find what is equivalent for this function `HASHBYTES('sha1', password)` in C# code.

Generated values of `HASHBYTES('sha1', "Glenw00d@3")` in T-SQL is `"Ð·mG>”TëÏåÈ“ÇOó26¥"`

Does C# have an equivalent of this T-SQL function or not?

UPDATE:

I tried to use this code:

```
  public static class SHA1Util
  {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute hash for string encoded as UTF8
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">String to be hashed</param>
        /// <returns>40-character hex string</returns>
        public static string SHA1HashStringForUTF8String(string s)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

            var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

            return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert an array of bytes to a string of hex digits
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">array of bytes</param>
        /// <returns>String of hex digits</returns>
        public static string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                var hex = b.ToString("x2");
                sb.Append(hex);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but it returns different results.

```
var hashString = SHA1Util.SHA1HashStringForUTF8String("Glenw00d@@3");//result for this was d0b76d473e945417ebcf18e5c893c74ff33236a5
```

Comment: You have to use this class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried but it return different value, I want to obtain from this string: "Glenw00d@@3" this hash ""Ð·mG>”TëÏåÈ“ÇOó26¥", using this library  I can't get it.Please see updated question.

Comment: It seems not very easy. What are you using the hash for?

Comment: I have an database with 2000 users.Previous developer did did store procedures for all logic, now we a trying to migrate a logic to c# ,so in this case has is use for storing user passwords.

Comment: So, I would to like this, if you don't find a reliable solution: Each time a user logs in you hash the password with the C# code and you mark the password as "hashed with c# code". In a certain time you will have most of the users migrated.

Comment: Well , I think there should be some equivalent code for this function  in c#,.

Comment: What is this "Ð·mG>”TëÏåÈ“ÇOó26¥" string? HASHBYTES does not return a string, it returns bytes. So it can't be true that this string is being returned.

Comment: I think too, it seems you are in the right direction with xanatos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you change the default endoding, normally SQL Server uses Windows-1252 for `VARCHAR()`.

```
private static readonly Encoding Encoding1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

/// <summary>
/// Compute hash for string encoded as Windows-1252
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">String to be hashed</param>
/// <returns>40-character hex string</returns>
public static string SHA1HashStringForDefaultString(string s)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(s);
```

---

**Found the problem**:

You are hashing **two different strings**

```
HASHBYTES('sha1', "Glenw00d@3")
```

and

```
SHA1Util.SHA1HashStringForUTF8String("Glenw00d@@3")
```

See the `@`/`@@`?

Now, for the encoding, I'll say that it is Windows-1252. But you can check with

```
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Columns.COLLATION_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Yourtable'
```

If the collation for your column contains the [`CP1` then it is Windows-1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx).

For the output... If you want a string, replace the return with:

```
return Encoding1252.GetString(hashBytes);
```

For `Glenw00d@@3` the hash is: `0LdtRz6UVBfrzxjlyJPHT/MyNqU=`

if you want an hex string, leave the return as is,

For `Glenw00d@@3` the hash is: `d0b76d473e945417ebcf18e5c893c74ff33236a5`

if you want it base64:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```

For `Glenw00d@@3` the hash is: `0LdtRz6UVBfrzxjlyJPHT/MyNqU=`

Comment: Thanks , but using this code I am not getting "Ð·mG>”TëÏåÈ“ÇOó26¥" for SHA1Util.SHA1HashStringForUTF8String("Glenw00d@@3"), Is a way to see what encoding is used , probably SQL Server is using different encoding.

Comment: Is the field a varchar, a char, an nvarchar, an nchar or what? If you go to the properties of a field, you should be able to see the collation

Comment: The field data type  is varchar(200).

Comment: @MDDDC Try `Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Columns.COLLATION_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Yourtable'` where Yourtable is your table name