# ExecuteScalar returns different result than Pure SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql

When I run this query in sql the result is 1 but same query running from c# result show 0

```
public static bool CheckUser(string UserName, string Password)
    {

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName = @username AND Password =HASHBYTES('SHA1','@password')";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,con))
                {
                  con.open();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);
                    return ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() > 0) ? true : false;
                   
                }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You perhaps don't need to surround `'@password'` with the quotes as it'll be quoted as a parameter.  Not certain that will cause the issue

Comment: @Martin That would indeed cause the issue. The `HASHBYTES` function is not recieving the value of the parameter (the value of the c# `string Password`) but a literal `@password`.

Comment: @Martin  still not working even I remove ' ' quotes from the password paramater.Is Their another method to call HASHBYTE encrypted Password from C#

Comment: Well you could hash the password in c# since sql server doesn't seem to execute the hashbytes part of that query. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155754/equivalent-of-sql-server-hashbytessha1-userpwd-in-c-sharp